# Memcached gem installation error in windows8

Tags: ruby, memcached

Am trying to install `memcached` gem in my windows 8.Am getting following error while executing the command `gem install memcached`

I already installed `Devkit` and using `ruby1.9.3`

```
C:\Users\aran>gem install memcached
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while.
```

..

```
ERROR:  Error installing memcached:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/ProgramData/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on Ubuntu an
d cyrus-sasl on Gentoo.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.  

 Provided configuration options

  --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=C:/ProgramData/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby   
Gem files will remain installed in C:/ProgramData/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/r
uby/gems/1.9.1/gems/memcached-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/ProgramData/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ge
ms/memcached-1.6.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

How can i rectify this error??

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora, I installed cyrus-sasl-devel. There might be same or something equivalent on Windows too...give it a try..